# Перенос колонок в bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всё перерыл, а ответа на главный вопрос так и не нашёл. Нужно что бы на самых меленьких мониторах колонки Col 1 и Col 2 занимали 50% экрана, а колонка Col 3 была под ними и занимала 100% экрана.

Перепробовал всё, ерунда какая-то получается. Помогите советом.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ">
      Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      Col 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      Col 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 " style="background:#357">
      Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background: #789">
      Col 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center ; background: #951">
      Col 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это первое, что я сделал. Но вот проблема оказалась в чём: у меня колонки подкрашены стилями:  и Col 3 закрашивает все остальные колонки и их просто не видно было. Стили простые : background-color:green;  Можно этого как-то избежать?

Comment: в смысле? а какому классу ты дал стили? может просто все сразу в один цвет красятся?

Comment: У меня добавлены классы a,b,c .c {
    // background-color:green;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
} У каждой колонки свой стиль. Если коментарий убрать, то остаётся одна колонка с зелёным цветом.

Comment: посмотри мой код, 3 колонки,2 по 50%, одна на 100%, у всех разные цвета. выложи свой код полностью посмотрим что там. а то так не понятно.

Comment: С твоим кодом такая же фигня: при уменьшении окна браузера остаётся только одна коричневая Col 3. Если убрать background: #951" то всё становится нормально. Видно дело в чём то другом.

Comment: Добавил картинку под кодом, у меня при уменьшении экрана все нормально работает.

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, что у меня локальный ботсрап кривой, сменил ссылку css на:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

И всё заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Ботстрап загружал в visual studio через nuget. Наверно просто кривой пакет. Щас напрямую загрузил стало всё нормально. Спасибо.